# Delete docker images from registry

Tags: linux, docker, registry

I want to make a script, that will delete old images from a docker registry, I've tried doing this task with a script that I've found on github (this [one](https://github.com/andrey-pohilko/registry-cli)), but it has some bugs, which deletes used layers, and this bug produces an error when we try to pull some undeleted images, the error is `unknown layer`.

Knowing that I have an ssh access to the registry, is it possible to make a script that is based on the system date of the manifest, and delete it with a system `rm`, in other words is the manifest system' date reliable to do this task.

Comment: @Zeitounator docker system prune won't delete images in the registry.

Comment: Oups, thouht you were talking about the local registry, my bad. Deleing my comment....

Comment: I actually delete redundant docker images, not by date, but only the latest one for each image name [delete_docker_images.sh](https://github.com/bbotte/bbotte.github.io/blob/master/shell/delete_docker_images.sh)